# Why is this variable coming from localstorage undefined? Angular 10

Tags: angular

In the component profile I make this `userTemplate` where I save all these variables. The values I get earlier from the database. I know that they work, because I printed for exmaple `voornaam`, `achternaam` and `id` and they give the right values. At the end I put the `userTemplate` in `localStorage`, so I can use those variables in another component.

```
this.userTemplate = {
        Email : this.email,
        Password : this.ww,
        UserID: this.id,
        Name: this.voornaam,
        Surname: this.achternaam
      }

      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.userTemplate))
```

In the component add-reservations I need to use the `UserID` from the `localStorage`, so I do this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   
    this.loggedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
    this.GebruikerId = this.loggedUser.UserID;
    console.log(this.GebruikerId)
  }
```

I also use `console.log` to see if the variable gives any value, but it's undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you confirm using dev tool that your local storage has `UserID` in it ? You can find it under dev tools --> application --> Local storage

Comment: Nothing looks unusual in above code; make sure you refers to correct localStorage instance and you have not set 'user' Item in storage from else where also.

Comment: when are you storing data in local storage ? what is the output on JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it will work or not but it seems that the loggedUser type can not matched. So try to define loggedUser value like below

```
loggedUser =  {
Email : '',
Password : '',
UserID: '',
Name: '',
Surname: ''
}
```

and then you can initialize the value from ngOninit(). Hopefully, it will work.